# GetADusers - with selected fields

Tags: windows, powershell, active-directory

I am trying to get all AD users into table in which the columns will be these fields:

> samaccountname, name, useraccount control, employeeid, employeetype,
>   distinguishedtype, title, department, manager, enabled, lockedout,
>   passwordexpired, passwordlastset, passwordneverexpires, lastlogondate,
>   whencreateddate, whenchanged, modified, accountexpirationdate, mail)

Then save it into excel/csv file

I tried this:

```
Get-ADUser -Filter | samaccountname, name, useraccount control, employeeid, employeetype, 
distinguishedtype, title, department, manager, enabled, lockedout, passwordexpired, 
passwordlastset, passwordneverexpires, lastlogondate, whencreateddate, whenchanged, 
modified, accountexpirationdate, mail
```

but i did not work well. Can someone help me with this script please?

Comment: `whencreateddate` -> `whenCreated`, and `distinguishedtype` -> perhaps `distinguishedName`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a few things.  First you need to populate the `-Filter` argument.  Second you need to tell `Get-ADUser` which properties to return.  Third, you need to output it to a csv file.

Also "WhenCreatedDate" should just be "WhenCreated" and "DistinguishedType" should probably be "DistinguishedName". I fixed those but left you casing.

Something like below should get you close:

```
$Properties =
@(
    "samaccountname"
    "name"
    "useraccountcontrol"
    "employeeid"
    "employeetype"
    "distinguishedname"
    "title"
    "department"
    "manager"
    "enabled"
    "lockedout"
    "passwordexpired"
    "passwordlastset"
    "passwordneverexpires"
    "lastlogondate"
    "whencreated"
    "whenchanged"
    "modified"
    "accountexpirationdate"
    "mail"
)

Get-ADUser -Filter * -Properties $Properties | 
Select $Properties |
Export-Csv -Path "c:\temp\Accounts.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

I'm not in a live environment, but tell me if this helps.  Thanks.

Comment: Great answer, although you may want to stick `Select-Object $Properties` in between `Get-ADuser` and `Export-Csv`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Yeah I thought about that because Get-ADUser won't populate it if it's not set in AD.  and I guess it'll give some extra properties too.  I don't recall if I have to calculate them though, was going to test then edit...

Comment: My reason for suggesting `Select-Object` before the export is to align the columns - `Get-ADUser` won't necessarily output the attribute values in the same order as the Properties list

Comment: @Steven Thanks a lot ! One more question. When I export it since I am from CZ, my users got diacritics in names. Am I able to export it in utf-8 so I will not get these "??" in names ? Thanks

Comment: Glad to hear it's working.  You can add the encoding parameter like: `Export-Csv -Encoding UTF8...`  I'm pretty sure UTF8 will support those characters too.  If you need to play around you have several encoding choices.